# SQLAlchemy 1.1.1 ignores lazy='joined'

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, mariadb

Have you ever found a case that if you put **commit()** after **session.query()** then SQL is executed separately for the every row in a query, SQLAlchemy **ignores lazy='joined'** in the model definition:

```
 ENGINE = create_engine("mysql+pymysql://........")
 SESS = sessionmaker(bind=ENGINE)     
 session = SESS()
 try:
    session.query(Document).order_by(desc('number'))[0:5]
    session.commit()
 except:
    session.rollback()
    raise
```

Model is as usual:

```
class Document(BASE):
   """ Document mapping """
   __tablename__ = "document"

   id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
   number = Column(String)
   currency_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('currency.id'))
   currency = relationship("Currency", lazy='joined')

class Currency(BASE):
   """ Currency mapping """
   __tablename__ = "currency"
   label = Column(String)
   id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
```

Without **session.commit()** SQLs are:

```
    70306 10:32:52    149 Connect   venice@localhost as anonymous on venice
          149 Query SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0
          149 Query SELECT document.id AS document_id, document.number AS document_number, document.currency_id AS document_currency_id, currency_1.label AS currency_1_label, currency_1.created_at AS currency_1_created_at, currency_1.updated_at AS currency_1_updated_at, currency_1.id AS currency_1_id
FROM document LEFT OUTER JOIN currency AS currency_1 ON currency_1.id = document.currency_id ORDER BY document.number ASC
 LIMIT 5
```

but with **session.commit()** SQLs are:

```
170306 10:31:58   147 Connect   venice@localhost as anonymous on venice
          147 Query SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0
          147 Query SELECT document.id AS document_id, document.number AS document_number, document.currency_id AS document_currency_id, currency_1.label AS currency_1_label, currency_1.created_at AS currency_1_created_at, currency_1.updated_at AS currency_1_updated_at, currency_1.id AS currency_1_id
FROM document LEFT OUTER JOIN currency AS currency_1 ON currency_1.id = document.currency_id ORDER BY document.number ASC
 LIMIT 5
          147 Query COMMIT
          147 Query ROLLBACK
          147 Query SELECT document.id AS document_id, document.number AS document_number, document.currency_id AS document_currency_id
FROM document
WHERE document.id = 4357
          147 Query SELECT currency.label AS currency_label, currency.created_at AS currency_created_at, currency.updated_at AS currency_updated_at, currency.id AS currency_id
FROM currency
WHERE currency.id = 1
          147 Query SELECT document.id AS document_id, document.number AS document_number, document.currency_id AS document_currency_id
FROM document
WHERE document.id = 293
          147 Query SELECT document.id AS document_id, document.number AS document_number, document.currency_id AS document_currency_id
FROM document
WHERE document.id = 569
          147 Query SELECT document.id AS document_id, document.number AS document_number, document.currency_id AS document_currency_id
FROM document
WHERE document.id = 6521
          147 Query SELECT document.id AS document_id, document.number AS document_number, document.currency_id AS document_currency_id
FROM document
WHERE document.id = 7614
```

When the exception is generated, e.g. caused by a cheat field:

```
documents = session \
                .query(Document) \
                .order_by(asc("bad_field"))[0:20]
```

then the python outputs:

```
InternalError: (pymysql.err.InternalError) (1054, u"Unknown column 'bad_field' in 'order clause'") [SQL: u'SELECT document.id AS document_id, document.number AS document_number, document.currency_id AS document_currency_id, currency_1.label AS currency_1_label, currency_1.created_at AS currency_1_created_at, currency_1.updated_at AS currency_1_updated_at, currency_1.id AS currency_1_id \nFROM document LEFT OUTER JOIN currency AS currency_1 ON currency_1.id = document.currency_id ORDER BY bad_field ASC \n LIMIT %(param_1)s'] [parameters: {u'param_1': 20}]
```

and MariaDB log:

```
170306 23:29:09   195 Connect   venice@localhost as anonymous on venice
      195 Query SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0
      195 Query SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'sql_mode'
      195 Query SELECT DATABASE()
      195 Query SELECT @@tx_isolation
      195 Query show collation where `Charset` = 'utf8' and `Collation` = 'utf8_bin'
      195 Query SELECT CAST('test plain returns' AS CHAR(60)) AS anon_1
      195 Query SELECT CAST('test unicode returns' AS CHAR(60)) AS anon_1
      195 Query SELECT CAST('test collated returns' AS CHAR CHARACTER SET utf8) COLLATE utf8_bin AS anon_1
      195 Query ROLLBACK
      195 Query SELECT document.id AS document_id, document.number AS document_number, document.currency_id AS document_currency_id, currency_1.label AS currency_1_label, currency_1.created_at AS currency_1_created_at, currency_1.updated_at AS currency_1_updated_at, currency_1.id AS currency_1_id FROM document LEFT OUTER JOIN currency AS currency_1 ON currency_1.id = document.currency_id ORDER BY bad_field ASC LIMIT 20
      195 Query ROLLBACK
      195 Query ROLLBACK
```

Comment: Please display the generated SQL.

Comment: Added SQLs in the original post

Comment: How did it get to the `rollback`?  Did the `try` fail?  If so, what was the error?  (I am trying to refrain from ranting about 3rd party software.)

Comment: Exception looks as if it was properly propagated to DB

Comment: session.commit() is not called because the exception is raised first

Comment: 147 show `COMMIT` immediately followed by `ROLLBACK`?